# Find a key in nested object and replace its value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here is my fiddle : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/8dey39fu/)

By recursive iterations, I am able to find the key in object2 object3 and replace its value by the values from data2 data3 objects.

However, I am unable to replace the value if it is an array. (key called 'coordinates' in this case)
How could this be fixed?

```
function update(object, data) {
  function getAllKeys(o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
      if (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
        return getAllKeys(o[k]);
      }
      keys[k] = o;
    });
  }
  var keys = Object.create(null);
  getAllKeys(object);
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(k) {
    if (keys[k] && k in keys[k]) { // check if key for update exist
      keys[k][k] = data[k];
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `getAllKeys` method with:

```
  function getAllKeys(o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
      contains_object = Array.isArray(o[k]) && o[k].some(val=> { return typeof val == "object" && !Array.isArray(val);  });
      if ((Array.isArray(o[k]) && !contains_object)  || typeof o[k] !== 'object') {
        keys[k] = o;
      } else {
        return getAllKeys(o[k]);
      }
      keys[k] = o;
    });
  }
```

Note: `!(o[k] instanceof Array)` - http://jsfiddle.net/08pnu7rx/1/

Comment: Hey thanks! It worked for object2 & object3 but fails for this one. Please check :http://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/fL4ectvy/

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks :D

Comment: Hey, many thanks for the solution. Although this is an old post, just a small addition: If the property has a null value then we get error, that's why we need to add: `|| o[k] === null` within if condition in the `getAllKeys()` function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `typeof` also returns `object` for arrays.

You want to change your function to still assign the key when the object is an array.

```
function getAllKeys(o) {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
    if (Array.isArray(o[k]) || typeof o[k] !== 'object') {
      keys[k] = o;
    } else {
      return getAllKeys(o[k]);
    }
  });
}
```

Notice I swapped around the logic, so you *first* check for either an array or another non-object type. If that check passes, you assign the value. If not, you recurse.

You should note that this is not at all specific to arrays. You will have similar problems if you have a nested property that is a `Date`, for example.

Comment: Hi, it worked for object2, object but not for this one, please check http://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/fL4ectvy/5/

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that `typeof o[k] === 'object'` returns true even it o[k] is an array which is the case for coordinated, You need a negative check for array too like

```
Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
  if (typeof o[k] === 'object'&& !Array.isArray(o[k])) {
    return getAllKeys(o[k]);
  }
  keys[k] = o;
});
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dey39fu/18/)**

According to the [docs or typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
// use Array.isArray or Object.prototype.toString.call
// to differentiate regular objects from arrays
typeof [1, 2, 4] === 'object';
```